# Блочный элемент не центрируется по горизонтали

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

header p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>
    center
  </p>
</header>
```

Подскажите, почему надпись "center" не располагается по центру?

Comment: Тег `p` - блочный и по умолчанию занимает всю доступную ширину, а текст в нём выравнивается по левому краю т.к. по умолчанию `text-align:left`. Чтобы выровнять текст по центру, задайте для нужного элемента `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь отцентрировать блок по центру. Но сам блок занимает 100% области. Чтобы отцентрировать текст используйте `text-align: center;` Или уменьшите блок с помощью свойства `width`.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать flex

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: green;
  align-items: start;
}

header p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>
    center
  </p>
</header>
```